# Flutter Listview not displaying text of foldernames in app storage

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I've been able to successfully download pdfs from my firebase database into my local app storage. I'm trying to display the names of the parent folders they were downloaded into, on a listview widget. My code displays the correct amounts of folders contained, but doesn't list the names of them on the listview. I've been trying to debug the code, and it prints out there is nothing in the folders even though I can see there is. I'm confused on what i'm missing or doing wrong.

Here is a screen shot
https://imgur.com/gg87acm

Download Code:

```
Future<void> downloadProtocols(String agencyName) async {

    globalAgencyName = "$agencyName"; // Change the value of globalAgencyName

    EasyLoading.show(status: 'Downloading...');

    try {
      // Fetch data under the "Protocols" node for the selected agency
      DatabaseEvent event =
      await _databaseReference.child(agencyName).child('Protocols').once();
      DataSnapshot snapshot = event.snapshot;
      dynamic data = snapshot.value;

      print("----------------------------------");
      print("Firebase Data Type: ${data.runtimeType}");
      print("Firebase Data Value: $data");

      if (data is Map<dynamic, dynamic>?) {
        // Check if data is null
        if (data != null) {
          // Iterate through the child nodes under "Protocols" and download each file
          data.forEach((categoryKey, categoryData) async {
            final categoryName =
            categoryKey.toString(); // Assuming category names are stored as strings

            if (categoryData is Map<dynamic, dynamic>?) {
              // Check if categoryData is null
              if (categoryData != null) {
                // Iterate through the child nodes under the current category and download each file
                categoryData.forEach((entryKey, entryValue) async {
                  final childNodeKey = entryKey as String?;
                  final childNodeData = entryValue as String?;

                  if (childNodeKey != null && childNodeData != null) {
                    final link =
                    childNodeData.toString(); // Assuming links are stored as strings

                    try {
                      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(link));

                      final agencynamedirectory = agencyName;
                      final categoryNamedirectory = categoryName;

                      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                        final appDocumentsDirectory =
                        await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                        final agencyDirectory = Directory(
                            '${appDocumentsDirectory.path}/$agencynamedirectory/$categoryNamedirectory');

                        // Create the agency directory if it doesn't exist
                        if (!await agencyDirectory.exists()) {
                          await agencyDirectory.create(recursive: true);
                        }

                        final filePath =
                            '${agencyDirectory.path}/$childNodeKey';
                        final file = File(filePath);

                        // Write the downloaded content to the file
                        await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);

                        // Print the download status and file location to the terminal
                        print("Downloaded: $link");
                        print("Stored in: $filePath");
                      } else {
                        print("Failed to download: $link");
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      print("Error downloading $link: $e");
                    }
                  }
                });
              } else {
                print("Data is null in Firebase for category $categoryName");
              }
            } else {
              // Handle the case where the data for the current category doesn't match the expected structure
              print("Invalid data structure in Firebase for category $categoryName");
            }
          });
        } else {
          print("Data is null in Firebase");
        }
      } else {
        // Handle the case where the data doesn't match the expected structure
        print("Invalid data structure in Firebase");
      }

      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Download Complete'),
            content: Text('All files have been downloaded successfully.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Close the dialog
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error downloading files: $e");
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

Display Names of downloaded folders on listview from storage:

```
Future<void> downloadProtocols(String agencyName) async {

    globalAgencyName = "$agencyName"; // Change the value of globalAgencyName

    EasyLoading.show(status: 'Downloading...');

    try {
      // Fetch data under the "Protocols" node for the selected agency
      DatabaseEvent event =
      await _databaseReference.child(agencyName).child('Protocols').once();
      DataSnapshot snapshot = event.snapshot;
      dynamic data = snapshot.value;

      print("----------------------------------");
      print("Firebase Data Type: ${data.runtimeType}");
      print("Firebase Data Value: $data");

      if (data is Map<dynamic, dynamic>?) {
        // Check if data is null
        if (data != null) {
          // Iterate through the child nodes under "Protocols" and download each file
          data.forEach((categoryKey, categoryData) async {
            final categoryName =
            categoryKey.toString(); // Assuming category names are stored as strings

            if (categoryData is Map<dynamic, dynamic>?) {
              // Check if categoryData is null
              if (categoryData != null) {
                // Iterate through the child nodes under the current category and download each file
                categoryData.forEach((entryKey, entryValue) async {
                  final childNodeKey = entryKey as String?;
                  final childNodeData = entryValue as String?;

                  if (childNodeKey != null && childNodeData != null) {
                    final link =
                    childNodeData.toString(); // Assuming links are stored as strings

                    try {
                      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(link));

                      final agencynamedirectory = agencyName;
                      final categoryNamedirectory = categoryName;

                      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                        final appDocumentsDirectory =
                        await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                        final agencyDirectory = Directory(
                            '${appDocumentsDirectory.path}/$agencynamedirectory/$categoryNamedirectory');

                        // Create the agency directory if it doesn't exist
                        if (!await agencyDirectory.exists()) {
                          await agencyDirectory.create(recursive: true);
                        }

                        final filePath =
                            '${agencyDirectory.path}/$childNodeKey';
                        final file = File(filePath);

                        // Write the downloaded content to the file
                        await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);

                        // Print the download status and file location to the terminal
                        print("Downloaded: $link");
                        print("Stored in: $filePath");
                      } else {
                        print("Failed to download: $link");
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      print("Error downloading $link: $e");
                    }
                  }
                });
              } else {
                print("Data is null in Firebase for category $categoryName");
              }
            } else {
              // Handle the case where the data for the current category doesn't match the expected structure
              print("Invalid data structure in Firebase for category $categoryName");
            }
          });
        } else {
          print("Data is null in Firebase");
        }
      } else {
        // Handle the case where the data doesn't match the expected structure
        print("Invalid data structure in Firebase");
      }

      EasyLoading.dismiss();
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Download Complete'),
            content: Text('All files have been downloaded successfully.'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Close the dialog
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error downloading files: $e");
      EasyLoading.dismiss();
    }
  }
```